# socket error [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor HTTP server

Tags: python, sockets

I want to write code for a multi clients socket program, 
but I get Bad file descriptor, and I don't know how to fix it.
this is my first code in python I'm new in python.

my code:

```
import socket
import os.path
from thread import *

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 11111

#server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen(1)

def clientthread(client_socket):
    while True:
        rqst = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if ("GET" not in rqst) or (rqst == ""):
            client_socket.send("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n")

        FileName = rqst.split(" ")[1]
        print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % client_address
        print rqst

        if os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + FileName) == True:
            f = open(os.getcwd() + FileName )
            g = f.read()
            response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Content-Length: ' + str(len(g)) + '\r\n''' + g  
            client_socket.send(response)
            print response
        elif FileName == "/":
            f = open(os.getcwd() + "/index.html")
            g = f.read()
            response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Content-Length: ' + str(len(g)) + '\r\n''' + g  
            client_socket.send(response)
            print response    
        elif FileName == "/for.html":
            client_socket.send("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n")
            print "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n"
        elif FileName == "/move.html":
            f = open(os.getcwd() + "/index2.html")
            g = f.read()
            client_socket.send(g)
            client_socket.send('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n')
            print 'moved''http/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'      
        elif "calculate-next?num=" in FileName:
            num = int(FileName[FileName.find("=")+1:])+1
            client_socket.send(str(num))
            print str(num)
        elif "calculate-area?" in FileName:
            height = float(FileName[FileName.find("height")+7:FileName.find("&")])
            width = float(FileName[FileName.find("width")+6:])
            S = float((height*width)/2)
            client_socket.send(str(S))
            print str(S)
        else:
            response = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n"
            client_socket.send(response)
            print response
        client_socket.close()   
    client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()

while True:
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(client_socket,))
```

my error:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Eden\Desktop\HTTPserver\server2.py", line 15, in clientthread
>       rqst = client_socket.recv(1024)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
>       raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
>   socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a duplicate `client_socket.close()` line indented in your inner while loop. This means that you try to recieve data from the closed socket, which raises that error. Also, why are you closing the `server_socket` in the `clientthread` method.

Comment: OK I got what you say, but if i remove the client_socket.close() here:
http://pastebin.com/EY0F8B1P
the page wont stop loading.

why it happens?
thanks!

Comment: @Eden I do not understand what you are trying to ask, but it seems to be a seperate question that should be  [asked seperately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Im the op of the question and i tried to fix the code like you said to me but its didnt work well, now the page wont stop loading bc i removed the client_socket.close() from the loop

Comment: @Eden As I said before, you are having a different problem which should by [asked seperately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).