# Page won't stop loading python socket + error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, sockets

I want to write code for a multi clients socket program, at first I gotBad file descriptor and I fix it like said to me in this question:
[socket error [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708236/socket-error-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-http-server/33708991#33708991)
but now the page won't stop loading and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eden\Desktop\HTTPserver\serverV2.py", line 26, in clientthread
    FileName = rqst.split(" ")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I really don't know how to fix it
I assume that the two problem related to each other

```
import socket
import os.path
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 11111

#server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
   server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

server_socket.listen(1)

def clientthread(client_socket):
    try:
        while True:
            rqst = client_socket.recv(1024)
            if ("GET" not in rqst) or (rqst == ""):
                client_socket.send("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n")

            FileName = rqst.split(" ")[1]
            print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % client_address
            print rqst

            if os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + FileName) == True:
                f = open(os.getcwd() + FileName )
                g = f.read()
                response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Content-Length: ' + str(len(g)) + '\r\n''' + g  
                client_socket.send(response)
                print response
            elif FileName == "/":
                f = open(os.getcwd() + "/index.html")
                g = f.read()
                response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Content-Length: ' + str(len(g)) + '\r\n''' + g  
                client_socket.send(response)
                print response    
            elif FileName == "/for.html":
                client_socket.send("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n")
                print "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n"
            elif FileName == "/move.html":
                f = open(os.getcwd() + "/index2.html")
                g = f.read()
                client_socket.send(g)
                client_socket.send('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n')
                print 'moved''http/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'      
            elif "calculate-next?num=" in FileName:
                num = int(FileName[FileName.find("=")+1:])+1
                client_socket.send(str(num))
                print str(num)
            elif "calculate-area?" in FileName:
                height = float(FileName[FileName.find("height")+7:FileName.find("&")])
                width = float(FileName[FileName.find("width")+6:])
                S = float((height*width)/2)
                client_socket.send(str(S))
                print str(S)
            else:
                response = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n"
                client_socket.send(response)
                print response   
        client_socket.close()
    except Exception:
        client_socket.close()
        import traceback
        print traceback.format_exc()

while True:
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(client_socket,))

server_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no spaces in your `rqst` variable. What is probably happening is that `rqst` is the empty string, which you specifically handle and then **continue processing the request as if it were valid**. Adding a `continue` statement in the first `if` would fix that.

Comment: OK thanks! The problem of the error IndexError: list index out of range Solved, but the page still won't stop loading.. I cant fins the source of the problem